# PHP SoapClient, Ruby wash_out, when passing params: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, ruby, soap

Here's my PHP:

```
    $url = "http://localhost:3000/api/wsdl";

    $client = new SoapClient($url);

    $params->a  = 'a Value';
    $params->b  = 'another Value';

    $client->AnOperation($params);
```

Here's a ruby controller using the wash_out gem that I'm using to create my soap server:

```
require "wash_out/soap"

class ApiController < ApplicationController
  soap_service namespace: 'urn:WashOut'

  soap_action "AnOperation",
              :args   => { :a => :string, :b => :string },
              :return => :string
  def AnOperation
    render :soap => "done"
  end

  before_filter :dump_parameters
  def dump_parameters
    logger.debug params.inspect
  end
end
```

Here's the WSDL that was generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:WashOut" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="api" targetNamespace="urn:WashOut">
  <types>
    <schema targetNamespace="urn:WashOut" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    </schema>
  </types>
  <portType name="api_port">
    <operation name="AnOperation">
      <input message="tns:AnOperation"/>
      <output message="tns:AnOperation_response"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="api_binding" type="tns:api_port">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="AnOperation">
      <soap:operation soapAction="AnOperation"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WashOut"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WashOut"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="service">
    <port name="api_port" binding="tns:api_binding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:3000/api/action"/>
    </port>
  </service>
  <message name="AnOperation">
    <part name="a" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="b" type="xsd:string"/>
  </message>
  <message name="AnOperation_response">
    <part name="value" type="xsd:string"/>
  </message>
</definitions>
```

When I run the PHP, I get "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string".

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be two things:

1) My WSDL cache was on for PHP.  It was caching an old version of the WSDL that I was developing in ruby.  You can shut the cache off at the runtime level, or at the configuration level.

2) My object structure for the request was off.  I was submitting the parameters via an object  with key/value pairs, but this was not being expected in the WSDL.  I adjusted my message for the operation in the WSDL to take a "part" that contains the parameters I'm passing.